# Are leading asterisks "**/" redundant in .gitignore path matching syntax?

Tags: git, gitignore, glob

Are there any usages that can't be replaced by equivalents without asterisks?

```
Two consecutive asterisks ("**") in patterns matched against full
pathname may have special meaning:

A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories.
For example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere,
the same as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory
"bar" anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".

A trailing "/**" matches everything inside. For example, "abc/**"
matches all files inside directory "abc", relative to the location
of the .gitignore file, with infinite depth.

A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches
zero or more directories. For example, "a/**/b" matches "a/b",
"a/x/b", "a/x/y/b" and so on.

Other consecutive asterisks are considered invalid.
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format

Let me point out, that i'm asking only about leading asterisks/slash redundancy. Since it seems any `**/foo/bar` can be replaced by simple `foo/bar`

For example, i have the following in my `.gitignore` file:

```py
# NuGet Packages

# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/packages/*

# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/packages/build/

# Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
#!**/packages/repositories.config
```

And i'm wondering, why they couldn't simply write:

```py
# NuGet Packages

# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
packages/*

# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!packages/build/

# Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
#!packages/repositories.config
```

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Answer (score 37):

No, the leading `**/` is only obsolete if the remaining pattern does not contain a slash except for a trailing one.

The documentation at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore is a bit misleading in my opinion, as it states

```
If the pattern does not contain a slash /, Git treats it as a shell glob
pattern and checks for a match against the pathname relative to the
location of the .gitignore file (relative to the toplevel of the work
tree if not from a .gitignore file).
```

but actually matches only against the name of a file or directory, not the whole path.

So `**/packages/build` matches `packages/build` in any depth.
`packages/build` as it contains a slash is effectively the same as `/packages/build` and only matches `packages/build` on the same level as the ignore file.

On the other hand `build` matches `build` in any depth so is effectively the same as `**/build`.
Whereas `/build` only matches `build` on the same level as the ignore file.

It always depends on whether the pattern (after removing a trailing slash if present) contains any slashes or not.

Comment: Isn't there a mistake in the documentation? I think one has to remove the not: ***"if the pattern does ???not??? contain a slash [...] checks for a match against the athname relative to ..***?

Comment: I'm not sure about the wording and exact meaning of "treats it as a shell glob pattern" and "pathname". You should discuss this at the Git mailing list.

Comment: Great answer, but poor UI.  Assuming this is completely accurate, then `build` should not be able to match any depth if `packages/build` does not match any depth.  That just leads to confusion.  This has convinced me:  I will *always* use the `**/<folder>` pattern, just to make the arbitrary depth obvious.   Thanks for a great answer, @Vampire

Answer (score 8):

There was (but isn't any more, thanks to editing) a faulty assumption in the question.  To demonstrate the issue:

```
$ mkdir tignore
$ cd tignore
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .../tignore/.git
$ git status -uall --short
$ mkdir sub sub/foo; touch sub/foo/bar; echo foo/bar > .gitignore; git status -uall -s
?? .gitignore
?? sub/foo/bar
$ echo '**/foo/bar' > .gitignore; git status -uall -s
?? .gitignore
$
```

In other words, to get Git to ignore the file `foo/bar` within subdirectory `sub`, we had to write `**/foo/bar` in the top level `.gitignore`, because `foo/bar` *does not* match `sub/foo/bar`.

**Note that the rules are different for ignore entries that do not contain an embedded slash.**  That is:

```
$ echo bar > .gitignore
$ git status -uall -s
?? .gitignore
$
```

Here we do *not* need the leading `**/`.  So leading `**/` is redundant when the name to be ignored *does not* contain its own embedded `/`, but is *not* redundant when the name to be ignored *does* contain its own embedded `/`.

For a longer treatment of the somewhat odd `.gitignore` rules, see [gitignore rules (applied to a codeigniter stack)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54772938/1256452).