# gitignore rules (applied to a codeigniter stack)

Tags: git, codeigniter

I'm adding a CodeIgniter website into a new repo (as an initial add - the repo is currently empty).

I've moved the `application` and `system` directories, and `index.php` from the CodeIgniter root into a subdirectory, `www`. I wanted to ignore the `development` and `production` directories I'd created in `application\config`.  https://www.gitignore.io/?templates=codeigniter uses `*/config/development/*`; this didn't work for me, but

```
**/config/development/*
```

did, which has led to a number of questions:

1. am I right in thinking that the `*/` at the beginning of `*/config/development/*` only refers to any immediate subfolder?
2. If so, what's the likely rational for gitignore.io including `*/` instead of explicitly using `/application/config/development/*'?
3. Because(?) I'd moved application to a subfolder, I found that I needed to change `*/config/development/*` to `**/config/development/*`

   - however, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41761521/889604 implies that `**/` is redundant *but* when I tried changing it to `config/development/*` the files were still added.  Do you only need to exclude `*[*]/` when the directory is in the same directory as the .gitignore?

Comment: The question and answer to which you linked (about leading `**/`) has a fundamental error (or, one could argue that Git has a fundamental error :-) ). I've attached a couple of comments there.

Comment: And I fixed my answer, sorry for the confusion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

In a `.gitignore`, patterns with *leading or embedded* slashes are treated specially.  They are different from patterns that have no leading or embedded slash.  So you may need `**/config/development/*` here because of the two embedded slashes.

#### Summary

To answer your questions in order:

1. Yes.
2. You'll have to ask whoever wrote those ignore files.
3. As I noted in a comment, the suppositions in [Are leading asterisks "**/" redundant in .gitignore path matching syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41761128/1256452) are wrong; the accepted answer there is not applicable to this case.

An explanation of this last item seems appropriate here.

## Long

For no obvious reason, Git's rule about whether a `.gitignore` pattern matches some file name found during some directory-tree-walk has a peculiar wrinkle.  If a pattern *does not* have an *embedded* slash, it's treated one way.  If it *does* have an embedded slash, it's treated a different, second way.  To really understand this, we need to define a few terms.

As a side note, I tend to like the term *directory* when talking about the OS-provided entities.  If you prefer the term *folder*, you can substitute that in mentally—they're essentially the same thing.  If you're familiar with C or Python or related languages, though, you'll know about `opendir` and/or `readdir` and/or `os.listdir`, and functions like `os.walk`, most of which also use the word "directory" to describe these things.

#### Defining glob patterns

Let's start with the `.gitignore` entries, which are made up of *extended glob patterns*.  The term *glob pattern* is pretty well defined at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), but we could use a bit more.

The most basic form of glob just has `*`, `?`, and `[...]` meta-characters.  A single question mark matches one character in a file name.  An asterisk matches any number of characters (including zero characters), and a square-bracketed string matches any of the characters inside the brackets.<sup>1</sup>  Note that this kind of simple, basic glob is applied only to files *within a single directory*.  Whatever entity is working with this kind of glob, that entity reads a list of file names—probably from an actual directory—and then selects those names within that directory that match that glob expression.

Obviously, the next level up is to add directories to this kind of simple glob.  For instance, we might write `dir/*` to mean *all files within the directory named `dir`*.  This is not very complicated, though it brings up a question we ignored with the simplest case: does a glob pattern match a *directory* name?  That is, what if `dir/sub` is itself a directory—does `dir/*` match it?  For that matter, does `*` match `dir`?  The typical answer is that, yes, this does match, and as long as we're sticking with `dir/*` that just means that `dir/sub` gets matched (as a directory).

Extended globs vary a lot.  [Bash has its own special extended glob syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html), using `globstar` to enable `**` and `extglob` to enable even more.  What `**` itself means varies: some implementations require it to match at least one directory, but allow any number of directory levels.  Other implementations allow `**` to match *no* directories, so that `**/sub` matches `dir/sub` but also just plain `sub`.  Git's `**` largely behaves this last way: it matches zero or more directories, according to [the gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that despite the resemblance, glob patterns are not at all the same as regular expressions, where typically `.` means any single character—the equivalent of `?` in glob—and `*` is a suffix *operator*, meaning zero-or-more of whatever came before.  Hence in regular expressions, `.*` means zero-or-more of any character.  R.E. square brackets usually allow for both ranges and inversion, e.g., [`^a-z]` means anything *not* in `a` through `z`, while shell glob patterns usually allow only ranges.

---

#### Git stores files via Git's index

In an important way, Git doesn't *care* about directories.  In particular, Git commits store *files*, rather than storing directories full of files.  The files simply have path names that *look like* they occupy directories.  The OS demands that the directory `dir` exist, so that `dir/sub` can exist; `dir/sub` in turn must be a directory so that `dir/sub/file` can exist.  But as far as Git is concerned, Git just needs to store content to go into a file that will be named `dir/sub/file`.  When it comes time to write that content into that file, Git will simply *create* `dir` and `dir/sub` if needed, *at that time*.  The presence or absence of the directories is irrelevant.

This is why you can't store an empty directory in a Git repository: Git stores the contents of *files* under *file* names in each commit.  With no files, there's nothing to store, so empty directories just are not present in a commit.

Nonetheless, while Git stores only *files*, Git must use the OS-provided directory reading services in order to *find* the files you have put into your work-tree.  Git will then copy those files—or more precisely, their contents, associated with their (full) names such as `dir/sub/file`, into Git's *index* when you prepare a new commit.  The index holds each file's name, mode (`100644` or `100755`), and the hash ID of the Git-ified content.  That's what will go into the *next* commit you make.  (When you `git checkout` some existing commit, Git fills the index from that commit, so that the index initially matches the commit.)

#### Walking a directory tree

As we just saw, Git has to open and read each directory in your work-tree, starting with the top level of the work-tree itself.  The results of calling `os.listdir` (Python) or `opendir` and `readdir` (C) is a list of names: file and sub-directory names within the directory that Git just told the OS to enumerate.  A bit more work (calling `lstat`) gets the rest of the information required, and now Git knows whether the name `dir` refers to an ordinary file, or to a directory.

Given the name of a *directory*, Git is generally going to have to open and read that directory as well.  So Git will open and read `dir` and find the name `sub`, and discover that `sub` is a directory.  Git will then open and read `dir/sub` and find the name `file`, and that `file` names a file.  This process of opening and reading, recursively, each directory *within* a directory, is called *walking the directory tree*.  That's what the Python `os.walk` function does, for instance.

Standard C does not have a function for walking a tree, so Git implements it all by hand, as it were.  This starts to matter in a moment, but for now, think of it this way: by walking the tree, Git finds *all* the directories and *all* the files in the repository.  Absent `.gitignore`, Git throws away all the directory names, keeps all the file names—using their full paths from the top—and then, at least for an "all" add operation, puts all those names and updated contents into the index, ready for the next commit.

There are several things to know about this:

- The walking process is inherently recursive.  That is, upon finding a directory, we must open and read the directory, handling each entry.  If the entry is itself a directory, we must open and read *that* directory, and so on.
- Meanwhile, each entry *in* a directory is just a name: we—or Git—must assemble the *path* as we go.  If we're working on `dir` and come across `sub`, the full name is now `dir/sub`.  If we're working on `dir/sub` and come across `file`, the full name is now `dir/sub/file`.  But `dir` just lists `sub`, and `sub` itself just lists `file`.  It's up to us / Git to remember the path.
- The walking process is *slow*, relatively speaking.  Git wants to be fast!

All of these introduce some of the complexities in `.gitignore` rules.

#### Gitignore files may exist at each level and list names and/or glob patterns

At the top level you can have a very simple `.gitignore` file:

```
# ignore files named *.o and *.pyc
*.o
*.pyc
```

Now Git can walk through your work-tree, finding files in each level of directory.  If the file's name—as expressed in that directory, at whatever level—matches any of these simple glob patterns, *and the full path name of that file is not already in the index*, Git will pretend that the file does not exist: it won't get automatically added, and `git status` won't complain about it being untracked.

But what if we want to prevent the file `dir/foo` and `dir/sub/foo` from going into the top level, while not protecting against `foo` in the top level?  Then we can tell Git: *only ignore `foo` when it's contained within in `dir`.*  There is an easy way to express this: create the file `dir/.gitignore`.  File names listed *here* are ignored when they're found by reading `dir` or any of its sub-directories:

```
.gitignore:
    *.o
    *.pyc
dir/.gitignore:
    foo
```

Now, during the walk, when Git opens and reads `dir`, it notices that there is a `dir/.gitignore`.  It applies the rules there to all files found during this recursive traversal: they apply to files in `dir` and files in `dir/sub`, but not to files in the top level, nor—if there's a top level `other/` directory, to files in there either.

#### Leading and embedded slashes avoid recursive matches

But what if we want to ignore *only* `dir/foo`, not `dir/sub/foo`, and not `other/foo` or `/foo`?  Now we have a different problem, and Git provides *two* solutions.  One of them is to write `/foo` as the entry in `dir/.gitignore`:

```
.gitignore:
    *.o
    *.pyc
dir/.gitignore:
    /foo
```

This ignores only `dir/foo`, not `dir/sub/foo`.  It contains a leading slash, which tells Git: *Don't apply this to sub-directories*.

Another way to express this is to put this right into the top level `.gitignore`, which removes the need to have a `dir/.gitignore` at all:

```
*.o
*.pyc
dir/foo
```

This contains an embedded slash.  When Git is doing a directory walk, it naturally finds file names stripped of their paths—it finds `foo`, not `dir/foo`, inside `dir` when walking through `dir`.  So this kind of pattern is handled separately, *after* putting together the full path name.

So, this is the source of the first two special rules about slashes in names or patterns in `.gitignore` files:

- A leading slash means *match only this name or simple glob in this directory*.
- An embedded slash means *match only this full path name or (extended) glob relative to this directory.*

Note that the second case covers the first one: both will work correctly, matching only paths within *this* directory, once the relative path names are put together (i.e., after `sub`'s `foo` is turned into `dir/sub/foo`).  But we need the first case because a *bare* name or glob pattern, such as `foo` or `*.pyc`, would apply to this directory *and* all of its sub-directories.  We could handle `dir/foo` by moving up to the top level and ignoring `dir/foo` directly, but if we want to ignore `/bar` without ignoring `dir/bar` and `dir/sub/bar`, we have only the top level `.gitignore` for this path.

This means you can invoke the full-path match—well, "full" relative to the directory in which the `.gitignore` itself lives—using a leading slash, an embedded slash, or both.  In general, if you create the `.gitignore` file as close as possible to the file, you'll need the leading slash rule.  If you use higher level `.gitignore` files, the embedded-slash rule suffices.

(The embedded slash rule might actually be a bug.  The wording in the gitignore documentation suggests that `dir/sub` is meant to ignore `a/dir/sub` as well, and that you would have to write `/dir/sub` to *not* ignore `a/dir/sub`.  But testing shows that it behaves the way I describe here:

```
$ git status -s -uall
?? a/dir/sub/file2
?? dir/sub/file
$ echo dir/sub > .gitignore
$ git status -s -uall
?? .gitignore
?? a/dir/sub/file2
$ git --version
git version 2.20.1
```

Note that ignoring `dir/sub` made `file` disappear, but `a/dir/sub/file2` remains complained-about.)

#### Trailing slashes are different

Remember that we said that the tree-walk is slow, relatively speaking.  It's pretty common to find a Git repository where, in the work-tree, we deliberately add an entire vendor SDK or other packaged thing—maybe taken from the repository as a single tarball, or maybe extracted in some method outside Git entirely—and never want to commit any of the files from inside this packaged thing, whatever it is.  Having Git walk through every level of that package, once it's unarchived, is just a waste of time.

To this end, if Git doens't already have an index entry listing, say, `dir/sub/vendor/file`, and—during one of its ambles through directory trees—comes across the directory named `vendor` in `dir/sub`, you can tell Git: *Don't bother to look inside this `vendor/` directory at all.*  One way to express this is to use what we already know:

```
.gitignore:
    *.o
    *.pyc
    dir/sub/vendor
```

or:

```
.gitignore:
    *.o
    *.pyc
dir/sub/.gitignore:
    /vendor
```

We already know what the leading slash is for here: it makes sure we only ignore `vendor` in `dir/sub`.  That's also already the case for the top level `.gitignore`.

However, what if we want to skip *all **directories** named `vendor`*, without skipping any *files* named `vendor`?  Here, we can use the *trailing* slash syntax:

```
.gitignore:
    *.o
    *.pyc
    vendor/
```

This `vendor/` looks like `dir/sub` in some ways.  But the slash here is not *embedded*, it's *trailing*.  So *this* slash does not turn on the full-path-only code.  Instead, it tells Git: *During your tree-walk, when you come across something named `vendor`, and it's a **directory**, don't bother recursing into it.*  The trailing slash is first *removed* from this string, leaving `vendor` is the item to match.  That has neither a leading slash, nor an embedded one, so it's matched at any sub-level of this level of the walk—but it does actually have a trailing slash, so it's matched *only* if what's actually in the tree is a directory.

Of course, we can also just say `vendor`, or `v*r`, or any other thing that matches `vendor`, if we're willing to ignore *files* as well.  Or we can write `v*r/` if we want to ignore all directories whose base-name—the part without the full path—matches `v*r`.

#### Un-ignoring a previous ignore rule, and the problem with ignored directories

Any entry in `.gitignore` that starts with `!` overrides a previous ignore rule that also matched this entry.  Note, however, for this to occur, *Git needs to have opened and read the directory* during its tree-walk.  If an earlier ignore rule allows Git to ignore a *directory*, Git does that *during the tree-walk phase*.

That is, if there's any rule that matches `vendor` at any point, and that rule says *do ignore this*, and `vendor` is a directory, Git *won't* open `vendor` and read its contents.  It *won't see* `vendor/file1`, `vendor/file2`, and so on.  Those names will never be brought under the *should we ignore this name* microscope, neither in their base-name `file1` format, nor in their `dir/sub/vendor/file1` full-path format.

#### Conclusions: what you should know about `.gitignore`

- A leading slash has an anchoring effect.  The anchor is at the same level as the `.gitignore` file.  (If the ignore file is outside the work-tree—e.g., is in `$HOME/.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude`—the anchoring level is the top level of the work-tree.)
- Embedded slashes—but not a trailing slash—turn on the anchoring effect too, despite the documentation's vague implied hint otherwise.  This might be a bug, but Git has behaved this way consistently through many releases (so maybe it's a *documentation* bug).
- Double-star glob matching (`**/whatever`) contains an embedded slash, almost by definition.  The only two double-star globs that do not have an embedded slash are `**/` and `**`, neither of which is likely to be used in practice.  Embedded slashes anchor names, but the double-star allows zero or more directory levels here, so that the anchoring has no inhibitory effect.  The leading double-star is required if you want this kind of free-floating match behavior on a name that, without the leading `**/`, would *also* contain an embedded slash.
- Un-ignore rules require that Git open and read a directory.  If you want to un-ignore some file deep in the directory tree, you want none of its containing directories to be ignored, or to find that something forces Git to scan the deep subdirectory.  That is, if you have a file named `long/path/to/important/file` and you want *that* file to be stored in each commit, you'll need *that name* to get into Git's index, so that Git will store it in the next commit.
- Files that exist in the index are, by definition, not ignored.  Ignore entries apply only to files that *aren't* in the index, but are in the work-tree.
- The index (always) exists, and it holds file names that—because the OS insists—actually appear inside directories.  So if the index has a `long/path/to/important/file`, Git will check to see if `long/path/to/important/file` is still there and has or has not been modified.  But if you've ignored `long`, or `long/path/to/important`, or something along the way here, Git won't *read the directory*.<sup>2</sup>  If you somehow accidentally *remove* `long/path/to/important/file` from the index while ignoring the directory `long/path/to/important`, Git won't add the file back again by itself, nor will it warn you that the work-tree file has become an untracked file.

---

<sup>2</sup>You can add a file that would otherwise be ignored using `git add -f`, and you can have a set of files in directories that aren't ignored, add some of those files to the index, then modify `.gitignore` to ignore their containing directories.  All of these result in files in the index that would not have gotten there by a more direct, or less forceful (`add -f`), method.  These are the cases I consider concerning: they are not *wrong* but they fall afoul of this last bullet-point.