# What's the difference between **/foo and foo in a .gitignore file?

Tags: gitignore

Are `**/foo` and `foo` in a `.gitignore` file synonyms?

For example, do these two lines do the same?

```
**/.DS_Store
.DS_Store
```

> A leading `**` followed by a slash means match in all directories. For
> example, `**/foo` matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same
> as pattern "foo".

Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format

Comment: Yes, they are the same. Your quote includes the answer: "For example, `**/foo` matches file or directory _foo_ anywhere, **the same as pattern `foo`.**" (emphasis added at the end)

Comment: This answer got me confused: `**/packages/build` matches `packages/build` in any depth. `packages/build` as it contains a slash is effectively the same as `/packages/build` and only matches `packages/build` on the same level as the ignore file. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41761521/7199922 So it makes a difference only if the line includes a slash if I understood correctly.

Comment: Ah, if you are using `foo` as a placeholder for _anything_, then they might not be equivalent because of this rule: "If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular .gitignore file itself. Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the .gitignore level."